# I am using google colab / python to analyze stock data and have issues combining / assigning the right index

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, stock

Here is how the data looks like:
[This is a snip of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iVSd.png)

Rows include:

```
Attributes  Adj Close   Close   High    Low Open    Volume
Symbols CVX INTC    CVX INTC    CVX INTC    CVX INTC    CVX INTC    CVX INTC
```

However, the stock symbols and Date and attributes cannot be called easily as it is. For example, CVX close and CVX low and Date are not even are the same row. I tried to pivot and also indexing but not yet successful. I am trying to have the column description all in one row and data as an index so I can perform analysis.

I tried the following first to index the date but it did not work:

```
data['Df'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

And unsuccessfully tried indexing the data:

```
 df_pivot = df.pivot('Date','Symbol','close').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the desired output is, but I wrote the code with the understanding that I want to process the stock name as a column. Is this the answer you intended? [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df_stock = web.DataReader(['CVX', 'INTC'], 'yahoo', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-15')
df_stock.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_stock.columns = [x[0]+'_'+x[1] for x in df_stock.columns]
df_stock = (pd.wide_to_long(df_stock, ['Adj Close','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume'],
                            i='Date_', j='Stock', sep='_', suffix='\\w+')
df_stock.head()
        Adj Close   Close   High    Low     Open    Volume
Date_   Stock                       
2020-01-02  CVX     114.918457  121.430000  121.629997  120.769997  120.809998  5205000
2020-01-03  CVX     114.520988  121.010002  122.720001  120.739998  121.779999  6360900
2020-01-06  CVX     114.132973  120.599998  121.669998  120.330002  121.239998  9953000
2020-01-07  CVX     112.675552  119.059998  119.730003  117.769997  119.019997  7856900
2020-01-08  CVX     111.388489  117.699997  119.089996  117.650002  118.550003  7295900
```